# How to reload a div after every 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = setupRefresh;
function setupRefresh()
{
    setInterval("refreshBlock();",3000);
}

function refreshBlock()
{
   $('#time').load("Callgen1.html");
}
</script>
```

I am stuck and wanted the div to reload after every 3 seconds. Any answer would be helpful. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am unsure why do you want to reload the div? Could you please be more clearer in the question. Thanks

Comment: actually i have a table under the div tag so i want to reload that table content so tryint to reload the table every 3 sec

Comment: Do you want to reload every time when your table data changes or you just want to reload the table to check if any new data has been pushed? Moreover, are you making an API Call to fetch the table data? If yes? You need not reload the div again.  You can just call that API again which would fetch and update the latest data in your table.

Comment: no i want itself to reload on its own after 3 sec and there is no api call basically the output is being parsed through jenkins here and pushed to git so i just need a html script that can reload the table so basically thats y i am trying to reload the div tag

Comment: i have made changes in code please look into it and would be happy if u v=can get a solution

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval you shouldn't use strings as first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes to your question, you need to pass reference to the function rather then string object in [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method.

please refer below answer, it will reload your div every 3 seconds, you can put your load method in place of my code "$('#time').html(new Date());" to solve your purpose

```css
*{color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      
function setupRefresh()
{
    setInterval(refreshBlock,3000);
}
setupRefresh()

function refreshBlock()
{
   $('#time').html(new Date());
}
</script>

<div id="time">test</div>
```

Comment: how to load a element id /div in that load?

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/jquery/jquery-load-method - refer link

Answer (score 0):

My guess is what you really want is to actually refresh 3 seconds after the prior one has finished so you do not pile up refreshes if it takes longer than 3 to load.  I added to the delay just so you can see it is doing that.

```js
async function delay(delayMilliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(timeToWait);
    }, delayMilliseconds);
  });
}
let timeToWait = 1000;

function redoLoad(forHowLong) {
  console.log("called redoLoad: " + forHowLong);
  // for fun, change the delay, then reset it again
  forHowLong = timeToWait >= 5000 ? 1000 : forHowLong + 1000;
  $('#time').load("Callgen1.html", function(responseText, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    timeToWait = forHowLong;
    sampleDelay(forHowLong);
  });
}
async function sampleDelay(waitTime) {
  console.log("before ");
  let delayres = await delay(waitTime)
    .then(function(v) {
      redoLoad(v);
    });
  console.log("after:" + waitTime);
}
sampleDelay(timeToWait);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">howdy</div>
```